# Xamarin Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to compile a solution that I did not write.  I keep getting the CS0234 errors, as well as many other database errors. I also can't seem to add any references since it says all the assemblies are already referenced.  The System.Data reference has a yellow triangle.  I tried restarting and rebooting several times.  I cleaned and rebuilt the project several times to no avail. How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update your PCL (the project referencing system.data) to .net standard 2.0. right click, properties, target framework

Comment: .net framework 2.0 is not an option.  I only have framework 4, 4.03, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.6.

Comment: .net standard 2.0 not .net framework 2.0. .net standard is the successor of PCLs. You can read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard and you can lower the version, if you need it (see section ".NET implementation support")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by copying over a folder full of dll's from my coworker's computer where the project was compiling successfully.

The folder was located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0

As soon as I copied the folder over and ran a clean & rebuild, the project compiled successfully.

Comment: Actually I found a better solution: In solution explorer, right click on references. Click on Add Reference. Click on Browse on the left panel. Verify the mono.android has a check mark on it. Click on Browse in the bottom. Enter this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1,  Select Mono.Android.dll.  This should add the reference to mono.android!